# Records are lost when sax inserts into a database in batches

Tags: node.js, zlib, sax, pg

I read a gz file using sax and zlib and then update my db,
its seems that i skipped some of my file content.

This is my code:

```
// variables to demonstrate the weired behovior
let recordsNum = 1;
let recordsNum2 = 1;
let numOfFailed = 0;

async function boo(...args){
  const saxStream = sax.createStream(true); // strict mode
  let currentElement = null;
  let currentObject = null;

    saxStream.on("opentag", (node) => {
    if (node.name === "Item") {
      currentObject = {};
    } else {
      currentElement = keyTransforms[node.name] ;
    }
  });

  saxStream.on("closetag", async (nodeName) => {
    if (nodeName === "Item") {
      // process the current object
      recordsNum++;
      if (arrOfRecoreds.length <= 100 && currentObject) {
        arrOfRecoreds.push(currentObject);
        recordsNum2++;
      }

      if (!currentObject) {
        numOfFailed++;
      }

      if (arrOfRecoreds.length === 100) {
        await insertBatch(arrOfRecoreds);
        arrOfRecoreds = [];
      }

      // reset the current object
      currentObject = null;
    } else {
      currentElement = null;
    }
  });


}

 const readStream = fs
    .createReadStream("./temp/" + fileName)
    .pipe(zlib.createGunzip()) 
    .pipe(saxStream);

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readStream.on("end", async () => {
      if (arrOfRecoreds.length > 0) {
        await insertBatch(arrOfRecoreds);
        resolve();
      }
    });
    readStream.on("error", reject);
  });


  return new Promise((res) => {
    pool.end();
    console.log("Finished processing file.");

    res({
      statusCode: 201,
      message: "update db",
    });
  });
```

where insertBatch function is just updateing db according the recoreds:

```
const client = await pool.connect();
  try {
    await client.query("BEGIN");
    await doSomthing(recoreds)
    await client.query("COMMIT");
    }

    catch(e){
    await client.query("ROLLBACK");
    }finally{
    client.release()
    }
```

The code works without errors but it contain some bugs i cant understand :

first bug:
when invoking the boo:

```
boo("str", "filename.rar").then(() => {
  console.log("num of recordes ", recordsNum);
  console.log("num of recordes2 ", recordsNum2);
  console.log("num of failed ", numOfFailed);
});
```

the logs are:
num of records 100
num of recordes2  45
num of failed  6

1. why recordsNum not equal to recordsNum2?
2. why there are some faild objects? the XML file is valid for sure !!!
3. the numbers of recordsNum2 and failed are changed each run

these bugs make this script problematic due to it not updating all the records in my postgress db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not declared `arrOfRecoreds` in your code.

Your `closetag` handler is asynchronous, but `sax` does not wait for asynchronous handlers to finish. This means that after you issue the database operation command `insertBatch(arrOfRecoreds)`, `sax` will continue parsing. Another `closetag` event will be emitted and new entries pushed into `arrOfRecoreds` *before* the database operation finishes and `arrOfRecoreds = []` is executed. At that point in time, everything that was pushed into it while the database operation was ongoing is lost.

This can be avoided if you don't await the database operation and reset `arrOfRecoreds` immediately after triggering it:

```js
if (arrOfRecoreds.length === 100) {
  dbOperations.push(insertBatch(arrOfRecoreds));
  arrOfRecoreds = [];
}
```

Here, `dbOperations` is an array that you declare as `var dbOperations = [];` in the same place where you declare `arrOfRecoreds`. It contains one promise per `insertBatch` operation, and you must wait for all these promises to become fulfilled before you can close your database connection at the end of the loop:

```js
await Promise.all(dbOperations);
pool.end();
```

Comment: U are superTight . i wounder why i got unvoted for my question.
(btw i solve it by my own before saw your answere, but didnt understood it from the doc. can u tell me how did u know it ? it took me long time to asume it ) big thanks

Comment: Own experience with sax.

Comment: The function works perfect without the await on the insertbatch. but when i run it on a loop , i have a problem due to at the end of the loop i close the connection to the DB with pool.end() 
but due to the insertbatch not awaiting , it continue using the pool after i ended it and it throw me an error. any solution?

Comment: i  solved it with another solution. If you intresting i can share my alternate solution. I will glad to hear your opnion